# How can I remove view from iCarousel and reload data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, icarousel

I am relatively new to IOS Development and I have implemented iCarousel in one of my ViewControllers. I am passing some data through a String array, and when I click a button on the carouselView, it should open up the photo library. Once I select an image from the photo library, I want to remove the value from the array and remove that instance of the iCarousel card.

I have looked around and have only found code in obj-c but I am using Swift.

I attached a picture of the iCarousel. When I click on the camera button, it will take me to the photo library, but once I select the photo, I want that instance of the carousel card removed.   [ViewControllerImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ6BT.png)

here is the code I am using for the iCarousel currently in the ViewController

```
    class ChallengesViewController: UIViewController, TabItem, iCarouselDelegate, iCarouselDataSource {
    var tabImage: UIImage?
    
   
    var image:UIImage? =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "camera")

    var masterchallengeList = [String]()
    var masterSubtitles = [String]()
    var weeklySelect = [String]()
    var weeklySubtitleSelect = [String]()
    
    enum StorageType {
        case userDefaults
        case fileSystem
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var carouselView: iCarousel!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        masterchallengeList = [“A “, “B”, “C”, “D”, “E”, F”, “G”]
        
        masterSubtitles = [“A “, “B”, “C”, “D”, “E”, F”, “G”]


        weeklySelect = ["","","","","","",""]
        weeklySubtitleSelect = ["","","","","","",""]

        
        for n in 0...(weeklySelect.count - 1){
            weeklySelect[n] = masterchallengeList[n]
        }
        for n in 0...(weeklySubtitleSelect.count - 1){
            weeklySubtitleSelect[n] = masterSubtitles[n]
         }
    }


    @objc func didTapCameraImage() {
        
        presentPhotoActionSheet()
        
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        carouselView.type = .coverFlow
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navigationItem.titleView?.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 3, green: 25, blue: 82, alpha: 1.0)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = "Challenges"
        
        
   
    }
    

    func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return weeklySelect.count
    }
    
    
    
    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
         let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 350))
        
        
          let lightBlue = UIColor.init(red: 94, green: 122, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0)
        
        
           tempView.clipsToBounds  = true
           tempView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
           tempView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0

            

        
        let actionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150))
        actionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        actionLabel.font = actionLabel.font.withSize(25.0)
        actionLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        actionLabel.text = weeklySelect[index]
        tempView.addSubview(actionLabel)
        
        let subtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: -30, width: 200, height: 150))
        subtitleLabel.center.y = tempView.center.y
        subtitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        subtitleLabel.font = actionLabel.font.withSize(14)
        subtitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        subtitleLabel.text = weeklySubtitleSelect[index]
        tempView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)

        
        let photoButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        photoButton.center.x = tempView.center.x
        photoButton.center.y = tempView.center.y + 92.5
        photoButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        photoButton.setImage( imageLiteral(resourceName: "camera"), for: .normal)
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                             action:#selector(didTapProfilePic))
        photoButton.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        
        tempView.addSubview(photoButton)
        
        return tempView

    }
    
       func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
       
       if option == iCarouselOption.spacing{
        return value * 2
       }
       

       
       return value
      }
    
    

       }


    extension ChallengesViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    

   
    func presentPhotoActionSheet() {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Picture", message: "How would you like to select a profile picture", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.presentCamera()
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.presentPhotoPicker()
        }))
        
        present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    }
    func presentCamera() {
        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        vc.sourceType = .camera
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.allowsEditing = true
        present(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
    func presentPhotoPicker(){
        
        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        vc.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.allowsEditing = true
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        guard let selectedImage =  info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else{
            return}
        image = selectedImage
      
        }
    

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
                                   animated flag: Bool,
                                   completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
               viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
               super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
             }
    
    @objc func dismissAlert(){
        customAlert.dismissAlert()      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just hide it iCarousel

```
carouselView.isHidden = true
```

But, if you want to remove it from its `superView` you must do it

```
carouselView.removeFromSuperView()
```

this line remove the `carouselView` from it's `superView` so in this case its `self.view`

Maybe you do not want to use `carouselView` after the removing from `superView`.
In this case you can go with;

```
carouselView = nil
```

so use

```
carouselView.removeFromSuperView()
carouselView = nil



weeklySelect.remove(at: selectedRowIndex)
```

Comment: will this remove the entire carousel view or that specific "card" that was removed from an array? I do not want to remove the entire carouselView.

Comment: I edit my answer, last line is required for remove data for iCarousel

Comment: see, the issue I am facing is that I don't know how to access the "selectedRowIndex" and where would I implement this code. thanks

Comment: Hey @SasankA, there's a `- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;` method for the implementation. Check the implementation of iCarousel. Type didSelectItemAtIndex in the blank space in your controller and it will complete the function.

Comment: its working to an extent but it is only recognizing index 0 for didSelectItemAtIndex. How and when would I call the didSelectitemAtIndex function

Comment: after deleting index, call `iCarousel.reloadData()` to reloading all data maybe this will be prevent from error.

Comment: I noticed the issue. As stated in the iCarousel documentation, "This method will fire if the user taps any carousel item view (not including placeholder views), including the currently selected view. This method will not fire if the user taps a control within the currently selected view (i.e. any view that is a subclass of UIControl)." which means that if I click the photo button, it will not fire the function

Comment: you can handle it via Notification or Delegation, if a control clicked inside, notify a function to handle `reloadData()`` manually

Comment: sorry I am new to iOS dev, could you explain how to do that